# Identify duplicate Groups using Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as described below and I need to find out the duplicate groups based on the columns - c2,c3 & c4 and name the groups accordingly. For any value in column C1, if the number of rows is same and has the same set of values on all the rows, then it's a duplicate group and should be labeled with the same group name, otherwise, it is a unique group.

Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
                   'C2': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3'],
                   'C3': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3'],
                   'C4': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3']
                   })
```

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Any help with this?

Comment: Your edit was rolled back. Please repost your question.

Comment: Let the original question remain unedited, easy for other users to follow. I will post a new question if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three steps

```
df['Newkey']=tuple(zip(df.C2,df.C3)) # make value to tuple 
s=df.groupby('C1').Newkey.apply(tuple)# make all value to tuple 

s2='G'+(s.reset_index().groupby('Newkey',sort=False).C1.ngroup()+1).astype(str)
df['Newkey']=df.C1.map(dict(zip(s.index,s2))) # map it back
df
   C1 C2 C3 Newkey
0   A  1  1     G1
1   A  2  2     G1
2   A  3  3     G1
3   A  4  4     G1
4   B  1  1     G2
5   B  2  2     G2
6   C  1  1     G1
7   C  2  2     G1
8   C  3  3     G1
9   C  4  4     G1
10  D  1  1     G3
11  D  2  2     G3
12  D  3  3     G3
```